# class method `self.` within class methods block `class << self` in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.5

**context:** I'm currently working with the [parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser) gem and trying to handle all cases of *what is a public method*.

I've written this next code, hoping it will fail on runtime. But it doesn't.

```ruby
class Foo
  class << self
    def self.met
      puts "I'm just a troll"
    end

    class << self
      def mut
        puts "Try and find me"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I'm wondering where is `met` callable (`Foo.met` would raise a `NoMethodError`)? And is this a useful Ruby pattern or just something I should not do, neither care about?

Comment: `Foo.singleton_class.met` obviously. You open a singleton class and define a method on its singleton class.

Comment: I'd love some explanation about the downvote... and @AlekseiMatiushkin I've been looking for an explanation of `singleton_class`, but every cases reference usage of `singleton_class` over instances of a class. Hence I really do not get the usage here :/

Comment: Downvote is not mine; I’ll post the answer explaining the details.

Comment: Upvoted for the sake of enthropy constancy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each object in Ruby has its own [singleton class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class). This is where all the methods of instances are defined.

Consider the following example.

```
class C; end
c1, c2 = C.new, C.new
c1.extend(Module.new { def m1; 42; end })

c1.m1
#⇒ 42
c2.m1
#⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `m1' for #<C:0x000055cb062e6888>

c1.singleton_class.instance_methods.grep /m1/
#⇒ [:m1]
c2.singleton_class.instance_methods.grep /m1/
#⇒ []
```

Singleton class is needed to make it possible to extend objects etc.

In Ruby, *everything is object*. Classes *are indeed objects as well*. That’s why each class has its own singleton class. And each singleton class has its singleton class.

```
c1.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class
#⇒ #<Class:#<Class:#<Class:#<Class:#<C:0x000055cb0459c700>>>>>
```

Methods defined on `foo` are *stored* in the singleton class of `foo`. Methods defined on `foo`’s singleton class are *stored* in the singleton class of the singleton class of `foo`. And so forth.

It’s not quite practical, but it’s still possible due to how Ruby treats everything as `Object`.